# Regex's are working, but code looks horrible

Tags: r, nested, tidyverse, text-mining

I'm cleaning up a long list of noun-phrases for further text mining.  They're supposed to be 1- or 2-word phrases, but some have `/` in a conjunction.  Here's what I've got:

```
library(tidyverse)
conjuncts <- tibble(usecase = 1:3,
                   classes = c("Insulators/Insulation",
                               "Optic/light fiber",
                               "Magnets"))
```

And I want:

```
wanted <- tibble(usecase = c(1,1,2,2,3),
                 classes =  c("Insulators/Insulation",
                              "Insulators/Insulation",
                              "Optic/light fiber",
                              "Optic/light fiber",
                              "Magnets"),
                 bigrams = c("Insulators", "Insulation",
                             "Optic fiber", "Light fiber", NA))
```

I've got something working, but it's horrible and non-extensible.

```
patternSplit <- function(class){
  regexs <- c("(?x) ^ (\\w+) / (\\w+) $",
              "(?x) ^ (\\w+) / (\\w+) \\s+ (\\w+) $")
  if(str_detect(class, regexs[1])){
    extr <- str_match(class, regexs[1])
    list(extr[1,2],
         extr[1,3]) 
  } else if(str_detect(class, regexs[2])){
    extr <- str_match(class, regexs[2])
    list(paste(extr[1,2], extr[1,4]), 
         paste(extr[1,3], extr[1,4])) 
  } else {
    list(NA_character_)
  }
}

anx <- conjuncts %>% 
  mutate(bigrams = map(classes, patternSplit)) %>% 
  unnest(cols = "bigrams") %>% 
  unnest(cols = "bigrams")
```

Which gives me what I wanted, but *blecchh*!

```
# A tibble: 5 x 3
  usecase classes               bigrams    
    <int> <chr>                 <chr>      
1       1 Insulators/Insulation Insulators 
2       1 Insulators/Insulation Insulation 
3       2 Optic/light fiber     Optic fiber
4       2 Optic/light fiber     light fiber
5       3 Magnets               NA
```

The top two problems (1) I have to run the rexex twice - once with `str_detect` to get the logical for the `if / else` and again with `str_match` to pull out the tokens. (2) I have do the double `unnest` to unwind the list structure.  And smaller problem (3) Can I get out of `if / else`, into `case_when` or `switch`?

I'll eventually be extending this to about a dozen patterns and use-cases.

Comment: Do you need anything different from `conjuncts %>%
  separate_rows(classes, sep = '/')` ?

Comment: Yes, depending on the pattern. Your code produces 'Optic' where I need 'Optic fiber'.  There are more patterns to add. E.g "Integrated circuits/microcircuits" will go to 'Integrated circuits' and 'Integrated microcircuits'  All the cases start with splitting at the `/`, but then the pieces are reassembled depending on the number of tokens on each side of the `/`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is solution using `/` as seperator to detect word phrases, then using ifelse to get desired result:

```
patternSplit<- function(x,p="[A-z]+[/][A-z]+"){
  x1<- stringr::str_extract(x,p)
  x2<- stringr::str_replace(x,p,"")
  return(cbind(val1=x1,val2=x2))
}

conjuncts<- cbind(conjuncts,conjuncts$classes %>% patternSplit()) %>% 
  tidyr::separate_rows(val1, sep = '/') %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(bigrams= ifelse(!is.na(val1),paste0(val1,val2),val1)) %>%
  dplyr::select(-contains("val"))

conjuncts
  usecase               classes     bigrams
1       1 Insulators/Insulation  Insulators
2       1 Insulators/Insulation  Insulation
3       2     Optic/light fiber Optic fiber
4       2     Optic/light fiber light fiber
5       3               Magnets        <NA>
```